# 5 balanced equal masses on a circumference with varying distances between them

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics, statics

I'm looking for a way to calculate possible balanced positions of 5 equal masses on the circumference of a spinning wheel such that the distance along the circumference between the masses are all different, and no distance is an integer multiple of any of other the other distances.  This is like the balanced centrifuge problem, but without defined slots.

Update...
It may be taboo to cross-post to both Mathematics AND Engineering, but I did get step closer to the solution I'm seeking over there. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/54938/41450

I made the diagram below by taking an existing balanced arrangement and then moved the vectors nose to tail to create these pentagons. This particular balanced arrangement doesn't meet the criteria of distances on the circumference being non-integer multiples. I just need to figure out how to go the other way, and make distorted equal sided pentagons, and then see if the resulting arrangements are non-integer multiples.

[image: this diagram]

Comment: This https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.10824.pdf is a link addressing the continuous problem. It's from a comment at https://mattbaker.blog/2018/06/25/the-balanced-centrifuge-problem/ . Perhaps it will help.

Comment: I've seen that paper but I'm not sure how it applies to this problem. I have constraints that the masses are all on the circumference of a circle and are balanced. A 5 point star arrangement meets the criteria, but spacing is all equal. Masses arrange equilateral triangle and then two more set directly across from each other also meet the criteria, but the triangle all have the same distance apart, and the pair are the same distance apart clockwise and counter clockwise. I'm looking for an arrangement between these two configurations that no two distances between masses is the same.

Comment: I conjecture that there is no such configuration. I've no idea how to prove that.

Comment: Points on a circle can be located by 5 real numbers, except we have no external standard, so we can consider one fixed, leaving the other 4 as variables. The condition that they balance is a 2-dimensional vector equation (or perhaps complex number equation) - namely that the sum of the five is $0$. This provides two equations, reducing the degrees of freedom from 4 to 2. However, there are no exact constraints on those other two variables.

Comment: Note that for any complex $z$ with $|z|\le2$ there exist real $a,b$ with $e^{\pi ia}+e^{\pi ib}=z$. So just pick any real $r,s,t$ with $0<|e^{\pi ir}+e^{\pi is}+e^{\pi it}|<2$, and then choose $a,b$ with $e^{\pi ia}+e^{\pi ib}+e^{\pi ir}+e^{\pi is}+e^{\pi it}=0$.

Comment: Do you understand my comment, spD?

Comment: No, I don't really understand it, but that's OK. The sum of 5 vectors to make a closed loop solved this for my needs.

Comment: OK, but if you have an answer, let me encourage you to post it here as an answer.

Comment: I did, but then someone said I shouldn't answer my own question, so I deleted that answer and put it in as an update to the question. If someone has a good simple way to express that geometric vector explanation, I'll definitely flag it as the answer.